# How to prevent Entry widget from losing focus when a function is activated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My program has 4 tkinter Entry widgets and a pyplot graph which updates in every tick.

This is the bit of my code:

```
def grafico(hora_tem, hora_negocie, tem, negocie):
   hora_tem.reverse()
   hora_negocie.reverse()
   tem.reverse()
   negocie.reverse()
   figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,3), dpi=80, facecolor='#454545')
   ax = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
   figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)
   ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(7))
   ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

   for label in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
       label.set_rotation(45)

   chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, window)
   chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row=7, column=0, pady=0, padx=0)
   ax.grid(True)
   ax.patch.set_alpha(0.1)
   ax.set_title('Gráfico TEM/NEGOCIE')
   ax.plot(hora_tem, tem, '-r', label="TEM")
   ax.legend()
   ax.plot(hora_negocie, negocie, '-b', label="NEGOCIE")
   ax.legend()
   hora_tem.clear()
   hora_negocie.clear()
   tem.clear()
   negocie.clear()
   plt.pause(0.001)

def insert_text(var, text):
   var.set(text)
   return

def tick():
   insert_text(entry2, '{:.2f}'.format(price2))
   insert_text(entry3, '{:.2f}'.format(price3))

   insert_text(entry4, '{:.2f}'.format(price4))
   grafico(hora_tem, hora_negocie, tem, negocie)
```

The four params in grafico function are global variables with some timeframe and some value. When this function is activated I lose focus on the Entry that I'm typing in. Something is making the Entry lose focus but I can't figure out what

Comment: If you just update the `StringVar`s, you should not lose focus.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @acw1668 I am updating the stringvars, not sure what I am missing out

Comment: I have created a small script similar to yours and I do not have the issue.  So it should be something else causing the issue, not the code you posted.

Comment: @acw1668 I found out what function it is thats causing the focus to be lost. Ill edit the question

Comment: @acw1668 this part is causing the issue: chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row=7, column=0, pady=0, padx=0)

Comment: When `FigureCanvasTkAgg` is created, it will get the focus.  So you need to move the creation of it out of `grafico()` and `grafico()` is used to just update the plot.